# How to convert into decimal column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Using SQL Server 2000

table1

```
id values (datatype is nvarchar)

001 12:10 
002 01:25
003 10:01
004 21:20
```

I want to convert the values column into float..

Tried Query

```
Select id, Cast(Replace(values, '':'', ''.'') as float) as values from table1
```

Output is showing like

```
001 12.1 'zero is not showing
002 01.25
003 10.01
004 21.2 'zero is not showing
```

Why zero is hiding..? 2.10 or 2.1 is same for the float datatype but user will get confuse 2.1 like 2 hour  1 minutes instead of 2 hours 10 minutes...

How to solve this problem

Expected Output

```
id values (datatype is float)

001 12.10 
002 01.25
003 10.01
004 21.20
```

Need SQL Query Help

Comment: What is your presentation layer?

Comment: You are making a flawed assumption about numbers.  Numbers are not strings, the `missing zero` you mention doesn't exist.  What you are seeing is the string representation of a number.  If you copied this number in Excel, for example, then changed the formatting to `0.00`, you would see what you wanted.  If you used a format string in C#'s `toString()`, then you'd see what you want.  The answer is not to change your SQL, it's to correctly format the string representation of that number in your user front end.

Comment: Select id, Cast(Replace(values, '':'', ''.'') as DECIMAL(10,2)) as values from table1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`12.10` and `12.1` are both **string representations** of the *same* float (twelve plus one tenth). If you want the data type to be *float* you cannot specify its string representation. You can only do that when *converting* a float into a string, which would be a pointless exercise in your case (since you already have this value as a string).

Another data type instead of *float*, such as **[decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx)**, which has a fixed number of decimal places, might be a more appropriate choice for your task.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Select id, Cast(Replace(values, '':'', ''.'') as DECIMAl(10,2)) as values from table1
```